# Sylius API : Carts conflict on login

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, sylius

I'm using Sylius (Symfony SyliusBundle) as backend with a mobile app and i'm facing problem with carts conflict. I'm using lexikJWT token with default sylius_shop_provider to authenticate my users. Authentication works fine, i can login and retrieve all my user's datas. Here is the problem :
Once authenticated, i create a cart, add items to it, all work OK. Now i log out, create a new user, and when i login with the new created user, i get the cart of my previous user !
I use the default `$this->get('sylius.context.cart')->getCart();`to create or retrieve cart, but the customer_id of the order has changed after login.
I have no idea why, no doc, nothing. I just checked the sylius code, and something must be related to this :
There is a listener called CartBlamerListener which override the cart customer if exists :

```
private function blame(ShopUserInterface $user)
{
    $cart = $this->getCart();
    if (null === $cart) {
        return;
    }

    $cart->setCustomer($user->getCustomer());
    $this->cartManager->persist($cart);
    $this->cartManager->flush();
}
```

It seems to find a already existing cart (the one of my previous user), and override the customer field with the new user one, but it shouldn't !!!

Any ideas what is happening ?

Bellow my security file:

```
api_login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            provider: sylius_shop_user_provider
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
        provider: sylius_shop_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out what was happening. 2 things :

1/ On interactive/implicit login, Sylius try to retrieve an existing cart (if the user added items to cart before to login, frontend mode). To do this, Sylius use something called 'cartContext', with several differents context. The first one try to retrieve a cart based on the channel (shop name) and the customer (current logged in user). If no cart is returned (my case), it uses another context which try to retrieve cart based on the channel (still the same), and the session. And this is where it selected the wrong cart, and affecting it to my new user. So i now have a cart which is initialy not mine.

2/ I know it get the wrong cart because of session. But i'm in stateless mode, so nothing should be returned, and Sylius should have created a new one for me, but it doesn't. A session exists for my new user and appears to be the same as the last user.  It seems that Symfony start a session if form_login auth mode is set in the firewall configuration, no matter you do, it starts a session.

So what we have : Sylius gets the wrong cart because of session context. Symfony indeed start a session on api login. But as i use react native as frontend, and it's not running in a webview, the session shouldn't be the same (i'm not passing any cookie or so, just auth via json web token, and it's different for my 2 differents users).Even if the auth is ok, my user are correctly logged in with corrects personnal infos, they share the same backend session. And it's where i don't figure out why. The only clue i have, i because of the react native simulator javscript debbugging mode, which may use a proxy and send session cookie. I'm absolutely not really sure about that, but well, why not :)

So now the workaround, and it's very ugly/hacky: I just set a global request listener which listen only on non html request, and invalidate the session..

Hope it could help someone else, i spent too many days on it.